# Resolver error when referencing external schema files

Tags: json, visual-studio-code, swagger, openapi, jsonschema

I have this openapi definition file in which I get this error message when rendering in Visual Studio Code extension OpenAPI (Swagger) Editor 4.6.4:

```
Resolver error at paths./pet.get.responses.200.content.application/json.schema.allOf.1.properties.pets.items.allOf.0.$ref
Could not resolve reference: #/paths/~1pet~1%7BpetId%7D/get/responses/200/content/application~1json/schema/allOf/0
```

I have the five JSON schema files stored in the same directory as the openapi spec file:

```
openapi.petstore-mod.json
owner-full.schema.json
owner-lite.schema.json
pet-base.schema.json
pet-full.schema.json
pet-lite.schema.json
```

I have tried to narrow down the problem, but have only found the following two properties:

1. The problem disappears when I remove one (any) of the PATHs.
2. The problem disappears when I use the inline (i.e. the ones defined in the open api spec file itself) schema definitions, instead of referencing the ones in separate files.

openapi.petstore-mod.json:

```
{
    "openapi":"3.0.2",
    "info":{
       "title":"Swagger Petstore - OpenAPI 3.0",
       "description":"This is a sample Pet Store Server based on the OpenAPI 3.0 specification.  You can find out more about\nSwagger at [http://swagger.io](http://swagger.io). In the third iteration of the pet store, we've switched to the design first approach!\nYou can now help us improve the API whether it's by making changes to the definition itself or to the code.\nThat way, with time, we can improve the API in general, and expose some of the new features in OAS3.\n\nSome useful links:\n- [The Pet Store repository](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-petstore)\n- [The source API definition for the Pet Store](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-petstore/blob/master/src/main/resources/openapi.yaml)",
       "termsOfService":"http://swagger.io/terms/",
       "contact":{
          "email":"apiteam@swagger.io"
       },
       "license":{
          "name":"Apache 2.0",
          "url":"http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html"
       },
       "version":"1.0.6"
    },
    "externalDocs":{
       "description":"Find out more about Swagger",
       "url":"http://swagger.io"
    },
    "servers":[
       {
          "url":"/api/v3"
       }
    ],
    "tags":[
       {
          "name":"pet",
          "description":"Everything about your Pets",
          "externalDocs":{
             "description":"Find out more",
             "url":"http://swagger.io"
          }
       },
       {
          "name":"store",
          "description":"Operations about user"
       },
       {
          "name":"user",
          "description":"Access to Petstore orders",
          "externalDocs":{
             "description":"Find out more about our store",
             "url":"http://swagger.io"
          }
       }
    ],
    "paths":{
       "/pet":{
          "get": {
            "tags":[
               "pet"
            ],
             "description":"",
             "parameters": [],
             "responses": {
                "200": {
                   "description": "OK",
                   "content":{
                     "application/json":{
                        "schema":{
                           "allOf": [
                               {
                                   "$ref":"#/components/schemas/PagingEntity"
                               },
                               {
                                   "type": "object",
                                   "properties": {
                                       "pets": {
                                           "type":"array",
                                           "items":{
                                              "$ref":"pet-lite.schema.json"
                                             }
                                           }
                                       }
                                   }
                           ]
                       }
                     }
                  }
                }
             }
          }
       },
       "/pet/{petId}":{
          "get":{
             "tags":[
                "pet"
             ],
             "summary":"Find pet by ID",
             "description":"Returns a single pet",
             "operationId":"getPetById",
             "parameters":[
                {
                   "name":"petId",
                   "in":"path",
                   "description":"ID of pet to return",
                   "required":true,
                   "schema":{
                      "type":"integer",
                      "format":"int64"
                   }
                }
             ],
             "responses":{
                "200":{
                   "description":"successful operation",
                   "content":{
                      "application/json":{
                         "schema":{
                            "$ref":"pet-full.schema.json"
                         }
                      }
                   }
                },
                "400":{
                   "description":"Invalid ID supplied"
                },
                "404":{
                   "description":"Pet not found"
                }
             },
             "security":[
                {
                   "api_key":[
                      
                   ]
                },
                {
                   "petstore_auth":[
                      "write:pets",
                      "read:pets"
                   ]
                }
             ]
          }
       }
    },
    "components":{
       "schemas":{
         "PagingEntity":{
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
              "limit": {
                "type": "integer",
                "example":10
              },
              "offset": {
                "type": "integer",
                "example":0
              },
              "totalCount": {
                "type": "integer",
                "example":1
              }
            },
            "required": [
              "limit",
              "offset",
              "totalCount"
            ]
        },
         "PetLite": {
            "allOf":[{"$ref": "#/components/schemas/PetBase"}],
            "properties": {
                "owner": {"$ref": "#/components/schemas/OwnerLite"}
            }
         },
         "PetFull": {
            "allOf":[{"$ref": "#/components/schemas/PetBase"}],
            "properties": {
                "owner": {"$ref": "#/components/schemas/OwnerFull"}
            }
         },
         "PetBase": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                  "id": {
                     "type": "string"
                  },
                  "name": {
                     "type": "string"
                  }
            }
         },
         "OwnerLite": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                  "id": {
                     "type": "string"
                  },
                  "name": {
                     "type": "string"
                  }
            }
         },
         "OwnerFull": {
            "allOf":[
               {
                   "$ref": "#/components/schemas/OwnerLite"
               },
               {
                   "properties": {
                       "gender": {
                           "type":"string",
                           "enum":["Male","Female","Other"]
                       }
                   }
               }
           ]
         }
       },
       "securitySchemes":{
          "petstore_auth":{
             "type":"oauth2",
             "flows":{
                "implicit":{
                   "authorizationUrl":"https://petstore3.swagger.io/oauth/authorize",
                   "scopes":{
                      "write:pets":"modify pets in your account",
                      "read:pets":"read your pets"
                   }
                }
             }
          },
          "api_key":{
             "type":"apiKey",
             "name":"api_key",
             "in":"header"
          }
       }
    }
 }
```

owner-full.schema.json:

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
    "allOf":[
       {
           "$ref": "owner-lite.schema.json"
       },
       {
           "properties": {
               "gender": {
                   "type":"string",
                   "enum":["Male","Female","Other"]
               }
           }
       }
   ]
 }
```

owner-lite.schema.json:

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
          "id": {
             "type": "string"
          },
          "name": {
             "type": "string"
          }
    }
 }
```

pet-base.schema.json:

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
          "id": {
             "type": "string"
          },
          "name": {
             "type": "string"
          }
    }
}
```

pet-full.schema.json:

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
    "allOf":[{"$ref": "pet-base.schema.json"}],
    "properties": {
        "owner": {"$ref": "owner-full.schema.json"}
    }
 }
```

pet-lite.schema.json:

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
    "allOf":[{"$ref": "pet-base.schema.json"}],
    "properties": {
        "owner": {"$ref": "owner-lite.schema.json"}
    }
 }
```

The same structures are defined within the open api spec file itself, just for test purposes.

Do you recognize the problem?

**Edit:** When I [switched renderer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=42Crunch.vscode-openapi#preview-openapi-documentation) to ReDoc instead of Swagger the problem disappeared. I filed the issue on [vscode-openapi github](https://github.com/42Crunch/vscode-openapi/issues/147)

Comment: The error message is referencing the schema in "pet-full.schema.json", which you did not include here.

Comment: @Ether thanks for pointing that out. I now added the complete source code.

Comment: This all looks fine to me.. I wonder if the evaluator you are using has a bug in its $ref resolution.